# Как правильно реализовать работу с PostgreSQL через ORM?

Tags: python-3.x, асинхронность, orm, sqlalchemy, asyncpg

При вызове метода add_user, ловлю ошибку `AttributeError: 'AsyncConnection' object has no attribute 'add'` Перепробовал уже много вариантов из интернета, в документации толком разобраться не удалось. Хотел бы понять как правильно организовать работу с асинхронной БД через ORM, как правильно в других модулях приложения создавать и передавать сессию и тому подобное.

Файл `database.py`

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, async_sessionmaker
from db.base import Base
from db.models import User
from datetime import datetime
from config import db_name, db_host, db_pass, db_user


DATABASE_URL = f'postgresql+asyncpg://{db_user}:{db_pass}@{db_host}/{db_name}'
engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, echo=True)
async_session = async_sessionmaker(
    engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False
)


class DataBase:
    async def create_tables(self):
        async with engine.begin() as conn:
            await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

    async def add_user(self, user_id: int, username: str, create_date: datetime.date):
        new_user = User(user_id=user_id, username=username, create_date=create_date)
        async with engine.begin() as session:
            await session.add(new_user)
```

Файл `models.py`

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, BigInteger, String, Date
from db import Base


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = Column(BigInteger, unique=True)
    username = Column(String)
    create_date = Column(Date)
```

файл `base.py`

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async with async_session() as session:
    async with session.begin():
        session.add(
            new_user
        )
```

Потому что нужно вызывать add на сессии, а не на конекте. В доках есть пример https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html

Comment: спасибо, подскажите, а это правильное использование соединения в многопользовательском приложении? Ведь, как я понимаю, после добавление юзера в этом кейсе оно сразу же закрывается. Или нужно создавать пул?

Comment: Не видя ваш сервер ничего сказать не могу